# Python - Manipulate String with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The following are Active Directory group Distinguished Names. I want to seperate out the leftmost name from the rest of the DN, as follows:

CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo = **CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM**

CN=OSGRP_IP_Transport,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo  = **OSGRP_IP_Transport**

CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo = **Remote Desktop Users**

So far the RegEx I have only matches the '_' strings. My RegEx is:

```
(?<=CN=)\w*
```

I'm also trying to figure out how to use the 're' module in Python. Currently my command is:

```
presplit = "CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo"
x = re.search("(?<=CN=)\w*", presplit)
print(x) >>> *returns* <re.Match object; span=(3,15), match='CTX_APP_Bytemobile'>
```

I want to obtain the match as a new string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `x = re.search("(?<=CN=)[\w\s]*", presplit)`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could do this without regex and just use `str.split` instead. For example:

```
s = 'CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo'

result = s.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
print(result)
# CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM
```

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* This is such a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there except for extracting matched string, you need to access it using `.group()` for full match. Following is your modified code,

```
import re

presplit = "CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo"
x = re.search("(?<=^CN=)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*", presplit)
if(x):
 print(x.group())
```

Which prints following like you expected,

```
CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM
```

Also, for capturing spaces as well, you need to use this regex,

```
(?<=^CN=)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*
            ^^^^^^^^^^^ This additional part enables it to optionally capture space followed by some word characters
```

If you notice, I have placed a `^` before `CN=` in positive look behind so it doesn't match other `CN=` in middle of the string and just `CN` in start of line.

**[Check this demo as well](https://regex101.com/r/detr7B/1/)**

Besides your positive look behind regex, you can use another simple regex, which is almost 20 times faster then look behind one but uses capture group. This `([^,]+)` part in following regex captures the name you are interest in.

```
^[^=]*=([^,]+)
```

**[This one is 20 times faster than earlier one](https://regex101.com/r/detr7B/2/)**

Check out this Python code,

```
import re

arr=['CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo = CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM','CN=OSGRP_IP_Transport,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo = OSGRP_IP_Transport','CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'^[^=]*=([^,]+)', s)
 if (m):
  print(s,'-->',m.group(1))
```

Prints,

```
CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo = CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM --> CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM
CN=OSGRP_IP_Transport,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo = OSGRP_IP_Transport --> OSGRP_IP_Transport
CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo --> Remote Desktop Users
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `x = re.search("(?<=CN=)[\w\s]*", presplit)`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want what is after the equals to the comma you could just split on the comma, set a variable to the position of the equal sign plus one and read it until the end.

```
presplit = "CN=CTX_APP_Bytemobile_UPM,OU=EEGroups,OU=EEOU,DC=ssa,DC=oam,DC=uk,DC=tmo"
#Make a list of strings split on the comma
lst = presplit.split(",")
#Iterate through the list
for i in lst:
    #Set the starting position to where the equal sign is plus one
    strt = re.search("=", i).start()+1
    #Get the string from the character after the equal sign to the end of the string
    print(i[strt:])
```